# Cannot Use the Disk Utility to Create Two Partitions on External HDD with High Sierra

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, high-sierra

I just bought a new external hard disk and I want to create some partitions. I am using the Disk Utility app in an High Sierra OSX MacBookPro.

However, the "partition" option for my hard drive is greyed out, therefore I cannot go ahead with the partition operation.

[image]

Although, when issuing the command `diskutil partitionDisk disk2 2 MBR fat32 "PART1" 80% fat32 "PART2" 20%`, I am able to partition, I cannot directly operate through Disk Utility.

How can I do this using the Disk Utility application?

Comment: It's a little vague here just based on the picture.  What happens if you issue the command (in Terminal) `diskutil partitionDisk disk2 2 MBR fat32 "Part1" 80% fat32 "Part2" 20%`   Post the results to your question.

Comment: @Allan When issuing the command `diskutil partitionDisk disk2 2 MBR fat32 "Part1" 80% fat32 "Part2" 20%`, the following message is displayed: *"Part1 does not appear to be a valid volume name for its file system".*

Comment: oops...make them all caps (i.e. "PART1")

Comment: OK now I see the two partitions, but still I cannot operate directly through Disk Utility.

Comment: So the functionality is there; its just the GUI isn't letting you do this.

Comment: The "partition" option in DiskUtility is available for my Machintosh HD (of course I don't what to partition my internal hard drive), but it is not for the external TOSHIBA disk. Do you know what is the reason for this?

Comment: I don't know why this is, but I did visit this once before and test it on my machine reproduced the results.  You'll have to go through Terminal.

Comment: if this ends up being closed, maybe the other question should be renamed a little more generically.

Comment: @dwightk - if it does get closed, having both names will give it two vectors to be found as this one will link to the target.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Disk Utility application can partition the external drive, if you use GUID Partition Map scheme.

Below is an example using a 16 GB flash drive.

1. Erase the drive.

   [image: e1]
2. Partition the drive.

   [image: E2]
3. Erase the first partition.

   [image: e3]

The results are shown below.

[image: e10]

[image: e11]

[image: e12]

Comment: Also works on Mojave

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting the drive as either APFS (if an SSD) or MacOS (Extended, Journaled if spinning drive). MBR is a windows technology and has various limitations on MacOS.

If it needs to be MBR, try renaming the drive to have <11 characters in the name as per the official documentation:

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH22240

Comment: The partition button is greyed out and unavailable (from screenshot).  Also, `TOSHIBA_EXT` is exactly 11 chars which qualifies.

Comment: The definition of a MBR existed before there was a Windows technology. Many other operating systems written by many other companies use the MBR. Apple's macOS requires an MBR.